# Did Sidious intend to kill Vader?

Tags: star-wars, sith

I don't assume the *Rule of Two* was followed so strictly, since Sith are the bad guys, they would not always play by the rules... But it seems that it was Sidious's way to have only one apprentice at a time.

As shown in RotJ, the Emperor had no problem in letting Luke kill Vader... He even encouraged him to do so, so he would *take his father's place at his side*... He did the same when Anakin fought Dooku in Episode III...

Had things went differently, and Luke was turned to the dark side, would Sidious just kill Vader, so that it would only have two Sith at a time?

Is there any material that exposes the Emperor's ultimate intentions in his plan of bringing Luke to the dark side, regarding this matter of slaughtering Vader?

Comment: The Sith philosophy is pretty much "survival of the fittest". Palpatine didn't particularly care which individual won, because either way he would presumably end up with the stronger of the two candidates.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you have to think about:

While The Rule of Two was the goal of the Sith since Darth Bane, it wasn't Palpatines goal - Palpatine wanted to implement the Rule of ONE - namely himself.

Palpatines had a need for a lackey, which functioned as a kind of scapegoat for the empire's crimes. So he could be seen as a wise and benevolent leader. (Same story with Tyrannus/Dooku and Grievous, really).

Comment: Vader was not an ideal accomplice.  Refer to: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32530/could-vader-really-have-crushed-the-rebels-on-hoth/32552#32552

Answer (score 0):

Sidious is a brutal character (he is a Sith after all) and if you take past happenings into account Sidious did ditch Count Dooku for Anakin. It is very likely that Sidious wanted someone who could wield the force as his apprentice and simply put, vader's suit made up most of his body. There were not enough mitichlorians for him to do advanced stuff like shoot lightening, but Luke could have learned to.

Comment: He could do basics like force wield and force choke though.

Comment: I'm not sure if force ability is the only way in which Vader's suit prevents him from using force lightening.  I imagine the electrical stuff in his suit would not react well to thousands of volts of current.