# Can the jump to light speed calculation be made ahead of time?

Tags: star-wars

After looking at the question, [Why do calculations need to be made before jumping into hyperspace?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68754/why-do-calculations-need-to-be-made-before-jumping-into-hyperspace) I have one of my own. Is there an in-universe reason that would prevent the calculation for the jump to light speed being made ahead of time to a safe haven? For example:

I'm a smuggler, wanted by a powerful clan of gangsters for losing a shipment of theirs, let’s say the Hutts. I'm about to land on the planet of Tatooine, where the need to make a quick escape is certainly more likely than normal. I have my computer make a calculation for a jump to light speed to a know safe haven. Then I land on the planet, knowing I can flee quickly without having to wait for the computer to make any lengthy calculations in case of emergency.

Is there any reason my above scenario could not occur?

Comment: See my answer to that referenced question.  Things in space are constantly moving at great speed in different directions.  You could make the calculations ahead of time, but then you'd have to recalculate over and over again every few minutes, or even seconds because your old calculation is no longer valid.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do calculations need to be made before jumping into hyperspace?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68754/why-do-calculations-need-to-be-made-before-jumping-into-hyperspace)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Logic would dictate that since the object would be to navigate around obstacles, any calculation would require:

1. Present location in space.
2. Desired destination.
3. Data about obstacles.

All of these variables would theoretically need to be calculated in real time, since everything moves. Yes, it could be predicted, but real-time data would be more accurate.

Also Han may not think ahead.

Comment: Upvoted your answer. However I think "All of these variables would theoretically need to be calculated in real time" is incorrect. The motion of most bodies in the universe (stars, planets, asteroid belts etc.). can be calculated ahead of time, as we know their motion and can map them out very effectively. (Humans and space ships can't be predicted, but it's impossible to know where they are so they can't be relevant in the calculations anyway.) Therefore I'd say that it can theoretically be claculated ahead of time, but practically would need to be in real time (mainly due to point 1).

Comment: I would have to argue that in order for calculations to be done ahead of time, you'd need to know exactly when you're jumping. It took Han a good amount of time to calculate when he was already in position. That means that checking for all possibilities "in the near future" and without an origin location would be complex, and likely would still require a good deal of refining calculations once a present location and time is known.

Comment: If you're making an 'unplanned, rapid exit' (aka: fleeing for your life), you obviously couldn't make the calculation in advance, because you wouldn't know *when* you'd be fleeing.  (If you did, you would have already left by then, wouldn't you?)  On the other hand, if you're taking a regular trip, where you know you'll be leaving at X time, you can pre-calculate the jump.  Of course, normally you're not evading turbo-laser fire while you make the calculation, so the few seconds it takes won't be much of a concern on a less life-threatening trip.

Answer (score 4):

That depends on what you mean. Hyperspace routes were usually not pre-calculated, because the changing nature of space could render a previously calculated route unsafe. However, there were certain routes called "[hyperlanes](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Hyperlane)" that were commonly used and known good routes. An example is the [Corellian run](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Corellian_Run), which carried a great deal of commerce. A route like this was essentially pre-calculated, as the route was known to be completely safe (from natural dangers, not necessarily pirates, etc).

The technical answer to your question is: yes, a route could be calculated ahead of time. They usually were not, because a route could later become unusable. Some routes were always usable and were thus essentially calculated ahead of time.

Answer (score 2):

> Without precise calculations we could fly right through a star or bounce too close to a supernova...

The main problem here appears to be the supernova.  We are currently unable to predict exactly when a supernova will happen, and from Han's words it seems to be enough of a concern to require the calculations to be done in real time.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that, generally, hyperspace calculations can be made in advance.  The only time we see the heroes worrying about the time to make the calculations, they simply haven't had the *opportunity* to do so.

For example, normal procedure would be to make the calculations and then take off, fly to the departure point, arriving at the calculated time, and make the jump.  When they're fleeing Tatooine, however, they didn't have the *opportunity* to do so.  They were trying to get off the ground as quickly as possible, while under fire.  Shortly thereafter, they're evading heavy fire from turbolasers on a Star Destroyer.

It's the difference between getting directions to your destination before you leave home, and doing so while being chased by the mob, after being shot at on your way to your car.

The problem with pre-calculating a jump when you "need to make a quick escape" is that the route is time-sensitive, and you probably won't know *when* you'll need to make said 'quick escape', especially not down to the level of precision needed to calculate the route.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes

According to *The Rise of Skywalker: The Visual Dictionary*, lightspeed skipping is accomplished using precalculated jumps:

> Poe has perfected hyperspace-skipping, a dangerous series of precalculated lightspeed hops meant to throw off First Order attempts at tracking.
>
> <sub>(page 90, Poe Dameron)</sub>