# Did the second Death Star have Interdiction capability?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Interdictor cruisers, cruisers that generate gravity wells to prevent ships from escaping, are shown in canon and Legends.  While the technology wasn't ready while the first Death Star was done (it was first shown in an early season of Rebels), was it added to the second one? It was said that the second Death Star was larger than the first one, so was that improvement added?

Comment: If DS2 could interdict the attacking Rebel fleet at the Battle of Endor, they wouldn't have needed the Imperial fleet there to prevent the Rebels from escaping...  (Recall that the Rebels used the Imperial fleet as cover to avoid DS2's superlaser.)

Comment: This [related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/68720/31936) (my own) has an [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/90849/31936) which says that the Empire had Interdictor cruisers, though there's no mention if the Death Star itself had gravity well generators.

Comment: @DavidW Historical note: in fact, that very plot point was the original impetus for Interdictors. According to Zahn's endnotes in the Heir to the Empire anniversary edition (p480): "The Interdictor Cruiser had been invented by West End Games, keying (I assume) off Admiral Piett's line in _Return of the Jedi_ that the Imperial forces at Endor weren't to attack, but merely to keep the Rebel ships from escaping."

Answer (score 8):

The Death Star II didn't have interdiction capability, but we learn in [*Star Wars: Battles That Changed the Galaxy*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Battles_that_Changed_the_Galaxy) there were indeed Imperial '[Interdictor-vessels](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Interdictor_vessel)' at the Battle of Endor.

These ships were initially effective in preventing the Rebel fleet from escaping back into hyperspace but then fairly promptly destroyed by the Rebel Alliance once the Death Star II's shield came down and the Imperial fleet fell into disarray.

[image]